# MySQL Workbench could not connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to migrate from SQLite to MySQL. I just installed MySQL Workbench from [here](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and rebooted.

I opened the workbench, click "New Server Instance", select localhost, next, leave database connection values as default.

```
Connection Name: localhost
Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)
Hostname: localhost
Port: 3306
Username: root
Password: Not set
```

> Message Log: Connecting to MySQL server localhost...
>
> Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

I don't think I'm doing anything obviously wrong?

Comment: And you already installed a mysql server locally?

Comment: [Better place](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install mysql server too. The workbench doesn't include it.

Comment: I don't remember doing this in the past but I will try now, thanks.

Comment: What a tricky situation lol. I did the same here. Worked (1st mysql server, 2nd mysql workbench).